# Set Datasource of Textbox to Inner Class in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a wpf gui page with a textbox that is bound to a property of an innerclass in my window. I have defined the textbox to be bound like so:

XAML:

```
 <TextBox Name="shhh" Text="{Binding Path=derpDerp, Mode=OneWay,
         UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

CodeBehind:

```
namespace ...
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        innerclass definition....

        public Herp derp;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            ...
            derp = new Herp();
            shhh.DataContext = derp;
            ...
        }

        {code that changes derp.derpDerp}
    }
}
```

InnerClass:

```
public class Herp : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private secret = "";

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Herp(string derp)
    {
        secret = derp;
    }

    public string derpDerp
    {
        get{ return secret; }
        set{ secret = value; onPropertyChanged("derpDerp"); }
    }

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }
```

What I was wondering is if I can declare the source of the textbox in the xaml. I have seen many examples that say to set the textbox to the datacontext of the parent like the window or a container around the textbox. However i don't find that very intuitive if only 1 control needs the data. It would make sense if I have several textboxes and a stackpanel with a datacontext.

In my implementation I create the object in code and set the datacontext to just the textbox. Is there an equivalent xaml solution?

Something like:

```
<TextBox Source="something" Path=derpDerp..../>
```

without setting a datacontext to a container or the window. Also, I didn't know how to set the datacontext of the window to my property correctly because it's an inner class with a namespace of the namespace.the window class or something like that.

What would be the proper way of just giving the textbox a datasource or if not possible how do I reference the innerclass and set the source to the window?

Comment: Take a look at the example in the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995743/how-to-properly-set-up-a-wpf-usercontrol-for-binding/17997265#17997265

Comment: That answer does what I do so that doesn't help. It doesn't set the source in the textbox without initializing in the codebehind

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create an instance of a class and set it as `DataContext` on any control in XAML. The general solution would be like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:Herp DerpDerp="This is Derp!!" x:Key="derp"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource derp}, Path=DerpDerp}"/>
</Grid>
```

Notice that I defined a new `xmlns` object called `local`, which points to the namespace in which the class I'm trying to create resides (in this case, it's `Herp`).Then, in my `Window.Resources`, I create an instance of `Herp`, and set a value for the `DerpDerp` property. Also notice that I gave the class a `key`, which is necessary in order for the `TextBox` to find it and bind to it.

**Big note:** In order for you to be able to create an instace of a class in XAML, the class **needs to have a parameter-less constructor!** So I changed `Herp` a little bit:

```
namespace MyProject
{
  public class Herp : INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private string m_derp;

    public Herp()
    {

    }

    public string DerpDerp
    {
        get { return m_derp; }
        set { m_derp = value; OnPropertyChanged("DerpDerp"); }
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, in your `TextBox`, you use the `Source` element in your binding to bind to the object:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource derp}, Path=DerpDerp}"/>
```

Comment: Ok I think I see what I was missing. Where you create the new xmlns object, you just set it to the outer namespace of the main window correct? I was thinking since I had an inner class that that would need to be different. Now there is no need to create a new Herp in code right?

Comment: You create the `xmlns` in the Window declaration in XAML. Yes, you won't have to create it in code anymore.

Comment: One more question. You say that the constructor needs to be parameterless? O, I see you just call the property and don't need anything in the constructor. I see. Thank you. I got lost with the inner class was my biggest problem I think

Comment: Ok I set the window resources to the xmlns object and referenced the property but it gives me this error:Error 1 The tag 'Herp' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:MyProject'. This is the same error I have been getting before which is why I went the code route.

Comment: @sisharp You need to change `MyProject` to whatever the namespace your `Derp` class resides in.

Comment: ofcourse but the class is an innerclass in the MyProject namespace

Comment: @sisharp So your `Herp` class is an inner class in `MainWindow`? Well, that itself is an indication of a bad design. Although you could expose the class as a property and bind to it, that is a VERY bad approach and could break in a number of ways. Binding entities should be defined in the own files.